# Why does a nested R function not recognize an existing object as an argument?

Tags: r, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing, nested-function

I have a series of three nested functions I am trying to run. I would like to specify the default arguments of the inner-most function as elements within a list-object that is passed fro the outer-most function. Since this is a little hard to explain I have created a reproducible example that uses the same arguments and objects as my original code. Please forgive the amount of code but I wanted to make this example as close to the original as possible.

The function `CreateBirthDates` is causing the issue. The four arguments are all elements within the list-object `sim` (e.g., `sim$agents$input`). I call sim to the first function, `wrapper`, and then again to the second function, `UpdateAgentStates`. Within `UpdateAgentStates` I would like to modify `sim$agents$input` using the other objects within `sim` (e.g., `sim$agents$birth_day`). Since these other arguments are always the same I would like to "hard-wire" them. But if I run the `wrapper` function, `CreateBirthDates` does not recognize `sim` and therefore cannot specify the default arguments.

I created alternate versions of `CreateBirthDates`:
`CreateBirthDates_with_sim`. This includes `sim` as an argument. Running this function with the wrapper function works!

This seems like a "this-is-the-way-R-works" issue but I don't fully understand why. I would like to improve my basic programming skills so any suggestion or comments would be most appreciated!

Thank you very much,
Javan

See code below:

```
    # Create some example data and load the package lubridate -----
    library(lubridate)

    t1 <- list("agents"=list("input"=data.frame(id=seq(1:5),class=rep("Male",5),age=rep(6,5))),
        "pars"=list("global"=list("input_age_period"="years",
                                  "birth_day"="01Sep",
                                  "sim_start"=as.POSIXct("2000-10-01"))))

     # Specify the original functions -------

     wrapper <- function(sim,use_sim=FALSE){

       if(use_sim==FALSE){
UpdateAgentStates(agent_states = NULL,sim=sim,init=TRUE)
       } else {
UpdateAgentStates_with_sim(agent_states = NULL,sim=sim,init=TRUE)
       }
     }

     UpdateAgentStates <- function(agent_states = NULL,
     sim = sim,
     init = FALSE
     ) {
       if (init == TRUE) {
input <- sim$agents$input
input <- CreateBirthDate(input)
sim$input <- input
return(sim)
       }
     }

     UpdateAgentStates_with_sim <- function(agent_states = NULL,
                          sim = sim,
                          init = FALSE
     ) {
       if (init == TRUE) {
input <- sim$agents$input
input <- CreateBirthDate_with_sim(input, sim=sim)
sim$input <- input
return(sim)
       }
     }

     CreateBirthDate <- 
     function(input = sim$agents$input, 
     input_age_period = sim$pars$global$input_age_period, 
     birth_day = sim$pars$global$birth_day, 
     starting_day = sim$pars$global$sim_start
     ){

       # Only proceed if there is no birth_date column
       if(is.null(input$birth_date)){
# Loop through each row in the input
for(a in 1:nrow(input)){
  # Is the age_period a year?
  if(input_age_period == "year" || input_age_period == "years") {
    # Determine the first sim_start date after the birth_day
    one_year <- as.period(1, "year")
    s0 <- as.Date(starting_day - (one_year*input$age[a]))
    # Set the format of the birth_day
    birth_day_format <- guess_formats(birth_day,"dm")
    birth_day_format <- paste(birth_day_format,"%Y",sep="")
    # Determine the first birth_day after s0
    s1 <- as.Date(paste(birth_day,year(s0),sep=""), format=birth_day_format)
    if(length(s1)>1){
      s1 <- s1[-(which(is.na(s1)))]
    }
    if(s0 >= s1) {
      input$birth_date[a] <- as.character(s1)
    } else {
      input$birth_date[a] <- as.character(s1-one_year)
    }
  } else {
    # If age period is not a year
    age_period_unit <- as.period(1, input_age_period)
    input$birth_date[a] <- as.character(starting_day - 
                                          (age_period_unit*input$age[a]))
  }
}
       }
       #  Convert birth_date to a POSIXct object
       #  input$birth_date <- as.POSIXct(input$birth_date, tz = 
       #    tz(sim$pars$global$sim_start))  
       return(input)
     }

     # Specify the modified functions -------

     CreateBirthDate_with_sim <- 
       function(input = sim$agents$input, 
       input_age_period = sim$pars$global$input_age_period, 
       birth_day = sim$pars$global$birth_day, 
       starting_day = sim$pars$global$sim_start, sim=sim
       ){

# Only proceed if there is no birth_date column
if(is.null(input$birth_date)){
  # Loop through each row in the input
  for(a in 1:nrow(input)){
    # Is the age_period a year?
    if(input_age_period == "year" || input_age_period == "years") {
      # Determine the first sim_start date after the birth_day
      one_year <- as.period(1, "year")
      s0 <- as.Date(starting_day - (one_year*input$age[a]))
      # Set the format of the birth_day
      birth_day_format <- guess_formats(birth_day,"dm")
      birth_day_format <- paste(birth_day_format,"%Y",sep="")
      # Determine the first birth_day after s0
      s1 <- as.Date(paste(birth_day,year(s0),sep=""), format=birth_day_format)
      if(length(s1)>1){
        s1 <- s1[-(which(is.na(s1)))]
      }
      if(s0 >= s1) {
        input$birth_date[a] <- as.character(s1)
      } else {
        input$birth_date[a] <- as.character(s1-one_year)
      }
    } else {
      # If age period is not a year
      age_period_unit <- as.period(1, input_age_period)
      input$birth_date[a] <- as.character(starting_day - 
                                            (age_period_unit*input$age[a]))
    }
  }
         }
         #  Convert birth_date to a POSIXct object
         #  input$birth_date <- as.POSIXct(input$birth_date, tz = 
         #    tz(sim$pars$global$sim_start))  
         return(input)
       }

     # Try running the wrapper function -------------

     # Original version, doesn't work
     wrapper(t1, use_sim = FALSE)

     # But if I add an argument for sim to CreateBirthDate
     wrapper(t1, use_sim = TRUE)
```

Comment: This seems like way too much code to sort through for a minimal, reproducible example. The `CreateBirthDate` function default values all seem to use `sim$` but `sim` isn't a parameter to that function. It's unclear to me ever what the desired behavior is. Everything here is running exactly as I would expect it to in R. Parameters in R functions cannot see variables outside it's own lexical scope. If you want a function to use a value, pass it in as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between using a global function within another global function, and defining a function within another function. In this first example the scope for inner_func is the global environment and sim does not exist in the global environment (the only variables that does is t1):

```
t1 <- 1

inner_func <- function() {
  final <- sim*2 
  return(final)
}

outer_func <- function(sim = w){ inner_func() }

outer_func(t1)

Error in inner_func() : object 'sim' not found
```

However if we define the inner_func inside of outer_func then you will get the behaviour you are expecting:

```
t1 <- 1

outer_func <- function(sim = w){ 
  inner_func <- function() {
    final <- sim*2 
    return(final)
  }
  inner_func()
}

outer_func(t1)
[1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I guess I'm confused why, if `CreateBirthDate` is nested within `UpdateAgentStates` and `sim` is included as an argument in `UpdateAgentStates`, why does `sim` not exist? I thought anything you supply to a function as an argument becomes part of the working environment and is available to any subsequently nested functions, if that makes sense...? Thanks again for your help!